Tabulator - Specify number of decimal on numeric field
I'm using Tabulator 6.2 and I want to specify the number of decimals on numeric field.
I read the data from a SQL table and show the data on the table but the value shown have a lot of decimal numbers
SQL Table

Tabulator Table

I want to reduce the number of decimal to 2. How can do it?

You can use a custom formatter function to change how the number is displayed: https://tabulator.info/docs/6.2/format#format-custom

Look at the column formatter "money"
https://tabulator.info/docs/6.2/format#formatter-money
